# My program is skipping a function in PHP

Tags: php, function, sms, delay, mailing

My PHP script was written to send email and SMS when some new information is entered in the front end to members in database. However the email code and SMS code are working individually, but when put together the code is not getting executed.

The code in fact skipped. I tried making a deliberate error in the called function but it did not recognize it. Why?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    define('INCLUDE_CHECK', true);

    require 'functions.php';
    include ("generatesms.php");
    include ("class.phpmailer.php");
    include ("../sendsmsV3.5/sendsmsV3.5/CurlProcess.php");
    include ("../sendsmsV3.5/sendsmsV3.5/Way2Sms.php");
    include ("class.smtp.php");

    // The above files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined
    $host     = "localhost"; // Host name
    $username = "root";      // Mysql username
    $password = "";          // Mysql password
    $db_name  = "test";      // Database name
    $tbl_name = "mails";     // Table name

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

    // Get values from form
    $subject  = $_POST['subject'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $phone    = $_POST['phone'];
    //$dept   = $_POST['dept'];
    $content  = $_POST['content'];
    $month    = $_POST['birthday-mm'];
    $day      = $_POST['birthday-dd'];
    $year     = $_POST['birthday-yyyy'];
    $date_eve = "$year-$month-$day";
    $dept     = $_POST['branch'];

    if (empty($dept)) {
        echo("You didn't select any DEPEARTMENTS.");
    } else {
        $N = count($dept);

        for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {   
            echo $dept[$i]; echo "<br>";
            $dep = $dept[$i];

            // Insert data into mysql
           $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(subject, body, dept, phone, email, date_eve) VALUES ('$subject', '$content', '$dep', '$phone', '$email', '$date_eve')";

           $result = mysql_query($sql);

           // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
           if ($result) {
               echo "Successful";
               echo "<BR>";
               newssender($dept, $content, $subject);
               generatesms($dept,$date_eve,$subject);

               echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
           } else {
               echo "ERROR";
           }
       }
    }

    // close connection
    mysql_close();
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show us ?

Comment: We can't answer without seeing the code. Could you edit it into your question?

Comment: ok.... i am very bad at guessing game....

Comment: If you could give us more visibility on your code & issue, we are more likely to be able to help you work through & solve the issue :)

Comment: My guess is that you didn't include some required file when you *"put together the code"*

Comment: Were there any errors output?
(display_errors = on in your php.ini)

Comment: how do i type the code.. i am so sorry. i am new to stackoverflow and i ma not able to format it :(

Comment: it says success but there is no mail in my inbox or sms in phone

Comment: @ShrestaBellary - so you're saying that `newssender()` and `generatesms()` both work if they're the only function called, but if they're both there, then - what happens? Could you also add the code for those two functions to the question, please?

Comment: If this isn't on a local server, then try running it on your development computer rather than a remote server. It sounds like you you have edited one file, but are executing another one. This sort of thing is much easier to spot if you are debugging locally.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have a big problem with all of your SQL.  You shouldn't use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and you're not sanitizing your inputs leaving you exposed to vulnerabilities. (http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)

If you could pose your `newssender()` function code I can give you a detailed/specific answer but in the meantime I will give a general solution that goes through some debugging processes for other users.

if you have code like this:

```
myFunction1();
myFunction2();
```

and `myFunction1()` is run but `myFunction2()` is NOT, you can try commenting out `// myFunction1()` (which it sounds like you did) and at that point if `myFunction2()` runs then obviously the problem resides in `myFunction1()`.  Here are the things to look for:

1. Fatal errors. Make sure you have errors and notices turned on to find syntax or other errors in your code
2. Look for any `die` or `exit` that may exist in your code. Those end the script and no more code is executed.

A quick way to test #2 is to do this:

```
myFunction1();
echo 'I made it here!';
```

If you don't see "I made it here!" on your screen then obviously the code didn't get that far, meaning the code ended before it returned from `myFunction1()`

I hope that helps!